# Не грузит state

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```
game.state.start('Home');
```

выкидывает исключение: Error: The value passed as the `game` argument (null) is not an instance of Phaser.Game.

```
console.log(game instanceof Phaser.Game);
```

выдает true в той же функции. В других stat'ах та же функция работает нормально.
С чем это может быть связано?

Проблема возникает после вызова:

```
game.load.onLoadComplete.add(fComplete,this)
game.load.start();
```

Comment: может проблема в том, что у вас нет стейта `Home`?

Comment: функция вызывается в других стейтах и ошибки не возникает, стейт прогружается. Но в конкретном стейте вызов функции вылетает исключение.

Comment: вы не поняли, вы передаете `Home` в  ф-цию `start`, вы уверены, что передает правильный параметр?

Comment: console.log(game.state) в списке содержит states в котором есть Home